# How do I add pkg-config the setup.py of a Cython wrapper

Tags: python, cython, setup.py, distutils, pkg-config

How can I add pkg-config to the following `setup.py` (for example if I want to add `glib-2.0`)

```py
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

wrapper = Extension(
    name="wrapper",
    sources=["wrapper.pyx"],
    libraries=["library"],
    library_dirs=["builddir/lib"],
    include_dirs=["lib"]
)
setup(
    name="wrapper",
    ext_modules=cythonize([wrapper])
)
```

I can do it as follows, but I don't want to use paths (`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` and `/usr/include/glib-2.0`) and make it portable

```py
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

wrapper = Extension(
    name="wrapper",
    sources=["wrapper.pyx"],
    libraries=["library"],
    library_dirs=["builddir/lib", "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/"],
    include_dirs=["lib", "/usr/include/glib-2.0"]
)
setup(
    name="wrapper",
    ext_modules=cythonize([wrapper])
)
```

Answer (score 7):

Getting some inspiration from [this recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/502261-python-distutils-pkg-config/), I've used the following setup file to find the proper paths for GSL.

```
import subprocess

from setuptools import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize


def pkgconfig(package, kw):
    flag_map = {'-I': 'include_dirs', '-L': 'library_dirs', '-l': 'libraries'}
    output = subprocess.getoutput(
        'pkg-config --cflags --libs {}'.format(package))
    for token in output.strip().split():
        kw.setdefault(flag_map.get(token[:2]), []).append(token[2:])
    return kw


example_src = ['src/example.c', 'example/example.pyx']
example_inc = ['include']
extension_kwargs = {
    'sources': example_src,
    'include_dirs': example_inc,
}

extension_kwargs = pkgconfig('gsl', extension_kwargs)

example_ext = Extension('example.example', **extension_kwargs)

setup(name="example",
      ext_modules=cythonize([example_ext], annotate=True),
      packages=['example']
      )
```

You could use the `pkgconfig` function to find the glib flags by passing `glib-2.0` as the `package` argument.